# How many Kosher animals were in Noach's Ark?

Tags: number, parshanut-torah-comment, animals, parashat-noach, mabul

How many animals total of each Kosher species were in the *teivah* during the flood?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Rabbeinu Bachyeh](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=38018&st=&pgnum=57), **16 of each**: 7 males for *korbanos*, 7 females for *korbanos*, and a male and a female for species preservation. (And same for the birds!)
According to others, 14 of each, 7 of each gender for both *korbanos* and species preservation.

Comment: Although, according to Rabbi Chavel, Rabbeinu Bachye is saying that there were a total of 14 of each Kosher species it is not proven that that is what he means. He seems to go to an awful lot of trouble to give over a p'shat that would be just like Rashi's opinion.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Sifsei Chachomim, Minchas Yehudah, and Be'er Yitzchak,  - 4 males and 3 females - 3 pairs for preservation and 1 male from each species for a Korban.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the number that Noah was commanded to preserve (7, 14, or 16 mentioned in the preexisting answers here), *Haamek Davar* notes that Noah was allowed to, and did, bring his personal animals on to the boat. Indeed, he says, the raven and (kosher) dove that Noah sent from the boat were his personal birds. He doesn't indicate how many personal animals Noah had on the boat.

I don't have *Haamek Davar* before me at the moment to cite it exactly, but it's in his commentary to the verses where Noah sends the birds out and the verse "כי אתך ראיתי צדיק לפני בדור הזה".